# Why did North Korea not broadcast internally an historical event such as Kim-Moon meeting?

Tags: north-korea, media

According to Washington Post, [Kim-Moon meeting was a historical event](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2018/04/27/the-historic-kim-moon-meeting-as-it-unfolded/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.8ad3999ed87d):

> In 2016, North Korean leader Kim Jong Un threatened to strike the
>   residence of South Korea's president with missiles, foreshadowing
>   mounting tensions that have kept the world on alert ever since.
>
> So, when Kim stretched out his hand and smiled at South Korean
>   President Moon Jae-in on Friday, the scene could hardly have been more
>   surreal.
>
> The historic moment was the result of months of negotiations and
>   pressure by both China and the United States, even though it remains
>   unclear how far North Korea is willing to give in.

The same article mentions a small detail related to how this event is seen inside North Korea:

> The summit was not broadcast live inside North Korea, and it remains
>   uncertain how much of the friendly scenes North Koreans will be able
>   to see.

Not broadcasting such a historical event involving the Supreme Leader seems strange.

**Question:** Why did North Korea not broadcast internally an historical event such as Kim-Moon meeting?

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based. While this is a good question, I don't think it has an objectively verifiable answer. Much of what the Kim regime does serves only to solidify the legitimacy of his own dynasty and nothing more. We don't even know if the summit itself was Un being genuinely interested in peace, or if he's got some angle he's trying to play. Who knows what's going on in someone else's head?

Comment: I would disagree. Who knows what's going on in someone else' head? Well, we sort of knows a lot. We know the fat buffon wants to live. We knows he wants to maintain his regime. An explanation how not broadcasting that could serve his goal would be beneficial. Not precise, but then, what is precise?

Comment: @J.Chang this is not a question about someone's thoughts.  It's a question about actions of the North Korean government.  Which makes it appropriate for this site.